# Symfony - requiring dependencies in use by another dependency

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

So, i am using the aws symfony [bundle](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony) (which uses guzzle. I see it in the sdk's composer.json and also files under the "vendor" directory). I want to use Guzzle directly in one of my services in my bundle. What is the best way that i should go about it?

(How does composer really work with regards to this?)

Comment: If you need it, add it as an explicit dependency. Ignore what other vendor libraries require.

Answer (score -1):

[Composer Packages Custom Installer plugin](https://github.com/farhanwazir/cpcinstaller) will help you to achieve your target. You will need to fork Guzzle package and edit `composer.json` and add simple type attribute and CPCInstaller dependency.

```
...
"type": "vendor-package",
"require": {"Yourname/cpcinstaller" : "1.*"}
```

[CPC Installer plugin](https://github.com/farhanwazir/cpcinstaller) is very easy to customize as you need. Best of luck

Comment: This doesn't help, the comment by Yoshi encouraging to add Guzzle as a dependency is the correct answer

Comment: OK, may be you skipped to see CPCInstaller instruction for use.